# Multiple comparison when testing one planned hypothesis

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons, contrasts, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate

I am running one logit model containing an interaction:

```
logit dv year contract_type yearXcontract+Z
```

where contract_type and year are dummies with 4 levels.

After running the model, I compute the marginal effects of contract_type (ref. permanent) in a given year. Then, I contrast the marginal effects of contract_type in a give year with respect to a reference year (2008). Contrast are run simultaneously and are 9 in total. For instance:

```
(Temporary vs Permanent)(1991 vs 2008)
(Temporary vs Permanent)(2001 vs 2008)
(Not employed vs Permanent)(1991 vs 2008)...
```

Should I adjust for multiple comparisons? If yes, what could be the most appropriate method in this situation? I know Bonferroni is excessively conservative. I also tried with Benjamini-Hochberg, but I am not sure it is appropriate with a limited number of comparisons.

Thank you.
Best regards,
Lydia

Comment: Did you do one comparison or multiple comparisons?

Comment: The outcome is one (whether they have a lower or higher likelihood of entering a marriage); the contrasts are multiple (listed above). And the hypothesis that is tested always contrasts a specific year and specific contract type, i.e. it is always (X vs permanent) and (Z vs 2008).